# What are termination callbacks during Akka ActorSystem shutdown implemented in Scala?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In my scala application I have an actor A that is the child of the guardian actor. The guardian actor has been given a one for all strategy to escalate on children shutdown.

Under various circumstances, the actor A calls `context stop self` that usually results in the entire application exiting, which is the desired behavior.

However, I recently observed a scenario where `context stop self` resulted in an error

> Failed to run termination callback, due to [Futures timed out after [5000 milliseconds]]

..and the actor system did not shutdown.

The application does sometimes have hundreds of thousands of actors under Actor A, and I wonder if shutting them down caused some sort of timeout in the termination procedure.

Can anyone help me understand why the behavior described above would happen and should I be using `context system shutdown` instead to shutdown the system?

Comment: http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2

Comment: @kukido I have read that before, but in my scenario it seems that the supervision tree and supervision strategy wasnt respected due to some sort of a timeout that isnt documented anywhere. This is what I am trying to understand

Comment: Do you drain the system from work before the shutdown? If not, then use `ActorSystem.awaitTermination()`. The call will block current thread until the system has been shutdown. This will block until after all on termination callbacks have been run.

Comment: I am struggling to explain the behavior I saw, I have been trying to follow akka source code to understand the same. i just dont understand which termination callback is being called and why is it timing out